# What is the complex integration?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

If $a \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|a| < 1$, then the values of $\displaystyle \frac{(1-|a|^2)}{\pi} \int_{\gamma} \frac{|dz|}{|z+a|^2}$,
where $\gamma$ is the simple closed curve $|z| = 1$ taken with the positive orientation.
What will be the integration?

I know this theorem:
$$\int_{\gamma} f |dz| = \int_{a}^{b} f(\gamma(t))d|\gamma|(t)$$
where $f$ is continuous on ${\gamma}$.

How do I use this theorem?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula

Comment: @GDumphart How do I deal with $|dz|$?

Answer (score 1):

On the positive oriented contour over the unit circle, we have
$\displaystyle\;|dz| = \frac{dz}{iz}$ and 
$$\frac{1}{|z+a|^2} = \frac{1}{(z+a)(\bar{z}+\bar{a})}
= \frac{1}{(z+a)(\frac{1}{z} + \bar{a})} = \frac{z}{\bar{a}}\frac{1}{(z+a)(z+\frac{1}{\bar{a}})}
$$
This means
$$\mathcal{I} \stackrel{def}{=} \frac{1-|a|^2}{\pi}\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{|dz|}{|z+a|^2}
= \frac{1-|a|^2}{\pi\bar{a}i}\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{(z+a)(z+\frac{1}{\bar{a}})} $$
The last integral is an ordinary contour integral. Since the integrand has only one root $-a$ inside the unit circle, we can evaluate it by taking the residue at $-a$. The end result is
$$\mathcal{I} = \frac{1-|a|^2}{\pi\bar{a}i}\times \frac{2\pi i}{-a + \frac{1}{\bar{a}}} = 2$$

Comment: I know only Lebesgue and Riemann-Stieltjes integrals. What is the meaning od $|dz$ here?

Comment: @Santiago, it means the arc length of the contour, On the unit circle with the parametrization $z = e^{i\theta}$, $|dz|$ is simply $d\theta$.